# repo sync interrupted in between due to computer crash

Tags: android, git, repository

I am trying to build a a custom rom based on PA. So I am trying to sync repo.

But today, suddenly there was a power cut and (dont know why) my ups just didn't give backup (it did give, but was a little lake.... i mean the pc got restarted).

So `repo sync` got interrupted in between.

My working directory is `home/android/system/`. I used the command:

```
repo sync
```

Please tell me what should I do. Should I continue or do it all over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the interruption occurred during the network phase, i.e. while Repo was downloading data, I'd be very surprised if you couldn't just rerun `repo sync` and have it pick up just fine.

If the interruption occurred while Repo was checking out the files from the downloaded gits it's not totally unlikely that you ended up with corrupted files. I'd just wipe everything in the workspace except the .repo directory (i.e. `rm -rf *` in the workspace's root directory) to avoid this problem, but running `repo status` after `repo sync` completes to make sure the workspace doesn't contain any modified or missing files should be fine too.